# Prediction Intervals and Tolerance Intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, prediction-interval, tolerance-interval

I have a question regarding interpretation of prediction intervals and confidence intervals.  The definitions I've seen is:

(1) A prediction interval for a single future observation is an interval that will, with a specified degree of confidence, contain the next (or some other prespecified) randomly selected observation from a population.

(2) A tolerance interval is an interval that one can claim to contain at least a specified proportion, p, of the population with a specified degree of confidence

My question is whether these definitions are equivalent to

(1) A prediction interval gives point estimates for the quantiles of a distribution.  So for example, a 95% confidence interval gives a point estimate for the 0.025 and 0.975 quantiles of a distribution.

(2) A tolerance interval gives (one side of) a confidence interval estimate for a quantile.  So for example, a 95% tolerance level for a 90% of the values gives a 1-sided confidence interval at 95% for the 0.05 and 0.95 quantiles?

Comment: (2) is correct; (1) is not.  See [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=prediction+tolerance+interval+is%3Aanswer+score%3A5) for more posts about prediction and tolerance intervals.